# Switch from motherboard graphics chip to graphics card just for games?

Tags: graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card

I just bought my first graphics card for games. It is a big monster with fans. Can I use it just for games?

I read somewhere, but may be mistaken, that the computer can’t handle 2 graphics cards at the same time. I was naively hoping that the CPU would use its native graphic chip and would complement it with the extra one when needed for graphics, or games.

If the graphics cards are mutually exclusive, I don’t want to use the noisy monster turbo jet for everyday use. Is there a way to easily switch between cards or do I need to disable/enable one of them every time I play a game or handle graphics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you connect your monitor to your desktop, you have to choose which input your want to use: the onboard gfx or your discrete card. If you wanted to swap, you'd need to disconnect and reconnect which I doubt you'd want to do all the time.

If you wanted to use two monitors, then yes. But together for one monitor, there is no combining.

It sounds like your graphics card makes a lot of noise at idle. Is it loud when you're not doing anything? What's the card specs?

Be good to know idle temps of the discrete card in case it is faulty.
I'd recommend using something like [HWMonitor](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/hwmonitor.html)

---

I'm not sure what monitor you have, but you could plug the onboard gfx into say DVI and the discrete gfx into DisplayPort. All you'd need to do is switch your monitor's display setting to which one you want without touching a cable.

Only problem is if your discrete gfx makes noise while just being plugged in and not used as the fans will still be turning while the card is plugged in.

Comment: i have an nvidia GTX, i was not expecting such a monster when i bought it online. no it is not noisy when it is iddle, but i don't want any noise when in general use or watching a movie for instance, which an onboard gfx can do without any problem for my small screen. i was also thinking of wear and tear, reserving the GPU for only when needed.